# F# and generics: can I have a collection of generic functions, each function having it's own generic type?

Tags: generics, f#

I would like to define a generic workflow like this (simplified)

```
type Fn1<'a> = RawInput -> 'a
type Fn2<'a> = 'a -> RawOutput
type Workflow<'a> = RoutingKey * Fn1<'a> * Fn2<'a>

type Workflows = Workflow list // <-- how to deal with it here?
```

I would like to filter through the workflows and when I find one, to process it so that each could have it's own `'a`.

Is something like the above possible? If not, what alternatives could I use?

---

EDIT

To shed a light to the problem:

My current workflow is just `RawInput -> RawOutput` and it was fine:

```
type Fn = RawInput -> RawOutput
type Workflow = RoutingKey * Fn
type Workflows = Workflow list
```

Now I need to step in the middle and do something "generic" in the middle of each workflow. So have decided to split it into two-step functions, but now I have no way to define the collection holding all the definitions.

---

EDIT #2

Trying to explain what I am doing more precisely: the original workflow needs to be split into to parts and "inject" some generic code in the middle, lets say:

```
type FnBefore<'a> = RawInput -> 'a 
// --I was wrong here: type FnVerify<'a> = 'a -> bool
type FnUniqueKey<'a> = 'a -> UniqueKey
type FnAfter<'a>  = 'a -> RawOutput
type Workflow<'a> = RoutingKey * FnBefore<'a> * FnUniqueKey<'a> * FnAfter<'a>
let workflows: Workflow list = […] // how can I declare'em all?
```

So, from now on, each workflow would define 3 functions instead of one and I want to keep all the workflows in one list, so I can pick one on each new message (based on RoutingKey). The `FnUniqueKey` is supposed to generate unique key for a verification function to lookup the database if the message was processed before.

Comment: The short answer is that it's not possible, but in order to suggest alternatives, we need to know what you're ultimately trying to do. This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: My current workflow is just `SomeInput -> SomeOutput` and it was fine, but now I need to step in the middle and do something "generic" in the middle of each workflow. So have decided to split it into two-step functions, but now I have no way to define the collection holding all the definitions.

Comment: Can you give a hypothetical example of inserting something "generic" like that? It's ok if it doesn't compile, just write something that would convey the idea.

Comment: Well, my original idea with "workflow function" was fine until I have realized I need to handle message duplicates. So, before processing the workflow I need to check if it's was already processed or not.

`SomeInput` is just a raw RabbitMQ message. Each workflow deserializes it, process and publishes response. I want to step-in after the message is deserialized and before processed – this deserialized message is the `'a` in my case.

Comment: Ok, if you just want to apply verification in the middle, why do you need to know the intermediate `'a` type at all? Each workflow can just have a function `RawInput -> RawOutput option`, where returning `None` would indicate failed verification.

Comment: The workflow processes `RawInput`s into `RawOutput`s, it's supposed to be pure function with some intermediate `'a` type in between. The verification function is generic/infrastructure code, it is supposed to look into the database to check if the message was already processed. So the verification function needs the `'a` (not RawInput) and I do not want the workflow business logic to care and to execute some DB functions. I want the workflow runner (not the workflow function itself) to verify/check for duplicates.

So, the workflow runner would ask for `'a`, verify it and hand it back.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no way to create such a collection, I have decided I will hide the `'a`, so each element will expose two functions, more or less like this:

```
type UniqueKey = UniqueKey of string

type Workflow = // the 'a is hidden within, I cannot see it from here
    { UniqueKeyGetter: unit -> UniqueKey
      Exec           : unit -> RawOutput }

type MkWorkflow = RawInput -> Workflow
```

Now, I can create a collection of `RoutingKey * MkWorkflow` and each `MkWorkflow` will "make a workflow" producing two functions:

- `UniqueKeyGetter` will provide a function closed over some unknown object decoded from `RawInput` (so I can tap in to check for uniqueness)
- `Exec` will be used only when workflow runner gives it a green light (by checking out the database of processed workflows based on `UniqueKey`

Now I can really hide the `'a`. This `MkWorkflow` scares me a little, it's one step in the "SometingFactoryProxyProducerGenerator"-hell from OOP frameworks, though.